# Prestashop (admin panel)

Tags: prestashop

I've installed Prestashop and when I'm about to log in at admin panel, it shows me  this message:

> Employee does not exist or password is incorrect.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error, perhaps, that cookies don't match in your MD5 hash of password.
[This link could help you to solve your problem](http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/others/prestashop/employee-does-not-exist-or-bad-password-prestashop-backend/)

Comment: Problem is , that  I don't have this file 'settings.inc.php' that is required to make the change on cookies..

Comment: Although this file is generated automatically during installation process by prestashop install wizard

Comment: yeahh i find it finally .. but in the beginning when i checked database nothing was store in employee  and ps_employee table , so i need it to add a user and after that i looked  that link that u recommended me , but is seems that nothing didn't affect in admin panel still the same ..

Comment: Thanks for your help  man , but I found the solution , the problem was  at timezone I need it to reinstall prestashop and change timezone to US .. anyway thnx  for trying to help , I really appreciate it :)